# Bind an event on a jquery generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this:

```js
$('.flag-icon-dz').click(function() {
  var lang = 'Arab';
  var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
  if (!$frame.size()) {
    console.log("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
    return false;
  }
  $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + lang + ')').get(0).click();
  $("li.ql-item.linkid188546").after("<li class='ql-item linkid18854777 closegoogle'><a href='#' class='btn-primary' target='_self'><i class='icon closegoogle ls-lang-frr' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>").fadeIn(500);
  $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeOut(500);
  return false;
});

$('.closegoogle').click(function() {
  $('.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-close-link > img').click();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid18854777').fadeOut('fast').remove();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeIn(500);
});
```

The first function works great, but the second doesn't. I realize that if I copy/paste the second function in the console **after** the first one, it works too.

I tried a few solutions (callback / setTimeout / jquery deferred / jquery .when method...) I didn't try promise but I don't think I have to in my context. Maybe I didn't write these solutions good enough.

I finally try to put my event (click) directly the `.before()` which create my new element like this :

```js
$('.flag-icon-dz').click(function() {
  var lang = 'Arab';
  var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
  if (!$frame.size()) {
    console.log("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
    return false;
  }
  $frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + lang + ')').get(0).click();
  $("li.ql-item.linkid188546").after("<li class='ql-item linkid18854777 closegoogle'><a href='#' class='btn-primary' target='_self'><i class='icon closegoogle ls-lang-frr' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></li>").fadeIn(500).click(function() {
    $('.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-close-link > img').click();
    $('li.ql-item.linkid18854777').fadeOut('fast').remove();
    $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeIn(500);
  });
  $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeOut(500);
  return false;
});
```

But it doesn't work either.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT :

I finally found a kind of solution for my second click event (which isn't the best solution but i works) :

```js
window.setInterval(function(){$('.closegoogle').on("click",function(){
$('.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-close-link > img').click();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid18854777').fadeOut('fast').remove();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeIn(500);
}); }, 1000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What i want to do is translate my page on click, and remove the translation on click, just like a toggleClass method can do. thx

Comment: You're creating your .closegoogle element after binding the click function. When your script is executed, it will bind your closing function to every existing element with the closegoogle class. But since you're creating those afterwards, it doesn't work. You should try to add your click listener after creating the element.

Comment: can you try this $('.closegoogle').on("click",function(){});

Comment: I tried but it do not work.

Comment: just to let you know, your "solution" isn't very good as you are binding a new click event every second

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice Pete, you are totally right. I try to find an other proper way to do this, but I don't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [delegated bind](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) as the element does not exist before you try your binding:

```
$('#parent-element-of-closegoogle').on('click', '.closegoogle', function() {
  $('.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-close-link > img').click();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid18854777').fadeOut('fast').remove();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Please note that the `#parent-element-of-closegoogle` needs to be an element that already exists when you do the binding - this can be `$(document)` if you hjave no other element to bind to

Comment: I tried your solution, but it don't work. The `#parent-element-of-closegoogle` is in an iframe (Google translate) and i think that it is a possible problem. I also try with `$(document)` but i did not works too. I don't have any error in the console.

Comment: if it is an iframe you need to bind to `$frame.contents().find('body').on`

Comment: I change it for `$frame.contents().find('body').on` but same result. This code works when i add it after in the console :
`$('.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-close-link > img').click();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid18854777').fadeOut('fast').remove();
  $('li.ql-item.linkid188546').fadeIn(500);`
but if i load all the code, the _close google_ function doesn't.

Comment: Does the frame exist when you do the binding or is it ajax loaded?  If the latter then what plugin do you use to show the iframe?  It should have an onloaded function in which you can do the binding

Comment: the frame does not exist yet. The `.goog-close-link` class loads only when this line is exectued : `$frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains(' + lang + ')').get(0).click();`

Comment: but what do you use to create the frame - I'm guessing it's a modal popup?  What do you call to create it? What plugin do you use?  I cannot suggest anything to you unless you create a [MCVE] as obviously there is not enough information in your question and you just keep changing the set up from the original context of what I answered

Comment: I use the official google translate widget : https://translate.google.com/manager/website/ . I will try to create an example and suggest it to you in comments. Thanks.